# Theoretical AJAX CSRF

Tags: security, csrf

I will use an example to phrase my question since it will make more sense. Lets say organization X uses session based authentication and has some endpoint Y that authenticated users send a GET request to with their browser in order to have a 'delete account' form rendered. As I understand it, typically, organization X will put in a nonce which gets embedded as a data attribute on the client's form. This nonce is supposed to stop CSRF.

What if malicious site Z has a script that sends out an AJAX GET request to endpoint Y and loads the HTML into a div with css style 'display:none;' on the same page as the script on site Z. From there, wouldn't malicious site Z have access to the nonce, which it can then use with the form rendered to submit a delete request on behalf of the authenticated user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question so let me know if that's the case, but here's how it should work:

> What if malicious site Z has a script that sends out an AJAX GET
>   request to endpoint Y and loads the HTML into a div with css style
>   'display:none;' on the same page as the script on site Z

Because of the same-origin policy, site Z cannot access the DOM objects on site Y, so it won't be able to read the nonce. The best it can do is load page Z into an IFrame, but that won't allow CSRF.

Answer (score 3):

Further to @akirilov's answer, loading another website into a frame can be a security risk for the framed website as this could create a [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attack.

This is where the content of the IFrame is hidden from the user, but is disguised by the UI on the attacking site.

e.g. say the following URL is loaded into the IFrame: `https://www.example.com/transferMoney?amount=1000000&to=999` where 999 is the attacker's own account and the victim is already logged into their bank at `example.com`.

`www.evil.com` can make the IFrame transparent and then place their own button underneath where the `Transfer Money` button would be rendered. The attacker's button could say something tempting such as `FREE iPAD!`. When the button is clicked the user is actually clicking the transfer button on the bank website and is non the wiser that they have just transferred money.

This sort of attack can be prevented by output of the [following HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to prevent a browser loading your page within a frame:-

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```